# Get Terms Count including Sub taxonomy - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[image]

I want to count the number of posts in each taxonomy. The below code only works if there is on 2nd level taxonomy. Based on the image. It's returning BMW Post count 2 but for Mercedez, it should return Post Count 4. Adding Model 1 & Model 2 post count.

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;
$termchildren = get_terms($taxonomy_name,array('parent' => $term_id));

foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) { ?>
<h3>
 <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($child);?>" class="stretched-link"><?php echo $child->name;?></a>
<span class="blog_bg_blue">Post Count: <?php echo $child->count; ?></span>
</h3>
<?php} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

**Script:**

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'parent' => 0
);

$categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach( $categories as $category ){
    print $category->name.' - '.$category->category_count.'</br>';
}
```

**Post arrangement in CMS:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]